# Python :Lambda Function Details in Decorator

Tags: python

Trying to add executing Process(**Test,a,b**) Name in the decoration where i am calculating Elapsed Time.Need Suggestions.

Final Expected Logs:

```
Process **a** elapsed time :3.8 || Rowcount=1833

Process **test** elapsed time :7.8 || Rowcount=1133
```

code

```
import time
from queries import a,b,test

def elapsedTimeTracker_decorator(func):
      def wrapper():
        start_time = time.time()
        func()
        print(test)
        end_time = time.time()
        elapsed_time = end_time - start_time
        print('elapsed_time:'+ str(elapsed_time) +'||' + 'RowCount:' + str(cursor.rowcount))
      return wrapper


    print "Process a started"
    elapsedTimeTracker_decorator(lambda: cursor.execute(a))()
    print "Process Test started"
    elapsedTimeTracker_decorator(lambda: cursor.execute(Test))()
    print "Process b started"
    elapsedTimeTracker_decorator(lambda: cursor.execute(b))()
```

a,b & test Consists of SQL Update Queries

```
test = """INSERT INTO users
select * from user_all where user_id=54549172 """
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to print extra data for a decorated lambda that takes no arguments, then you have to pass it to your decorator:

```
def elapsedTimeTracker_decorator(func, test):
    def wrapper():
        start_time = time.time()
        func()
        print(f'Process {test} elapsed time: {time.time() - start_time} || Rowcount={cursor.rowcount}')
    return wrapper

elapsedTimeTracker_decorator(lambda: cursor.execute(test), test)()
```

Other than that I have no idea where your `test` is supposed to comes from. Please elaborate with more details if that is not a suitable solution.

**EDIT:** Based on the latest information provided, it is clear that you do not need to use a lambda, nor a decorator with an inner wrapper. You could simply use a simple function that call the given one with the provided arguments and keywords that would take care of the call along with printing the execution time. For example:

```
from time import time as now

def time_call(func, *args, **kwargs):
    cur = now()
    func(*args, **kwargs)
    print(
        f'Executing {func.__qualname__}({repr(args)[1:-1]}, ' +
        f'{"".join(f"{k}={v}" for k, v in kwargs.items())}) took ' +
        f'{now() - cur} seconds.'
    )

def test(foo, bar, baz):
    pass

time_call(test, 'foo', 'bar', baz=None)
```

Which would prints something like:

```
Executing test('foo', 'bar', baz=None) took 0.0 seconds.
```

Comment: Test Consists Of SQL Query, Should i give alias to same

Comment: I think you should provide a more clear example with a complete executable code with valid variables and values because for now, your example is confusing. Names are missing, and you are calling something a decorator while not using it as a decorator and there is much better solution if your goal is to simply time a single call.

Comment: Thanks, updated the answer with a simpler solution.